# Is there a common name for this common chord progression

Tags: chords, chord-progressions

I've started listening to a specific genre of music which has its roots in Japanese Future Funk. In a lot of these songs I'm listening to, there seems to be a very common chord progression during the break in the middle of the song. I personally think this progression sounds very good, and as a music creator of sorts myself, I want to learn to construct these chords. The problem arises in when I can't seem to figure out the chords or even the notes that make them up. I can get the top and bottom notes, but I can't hear out the middle notes.

My question is does someone know this chord progression? Could you explain how these chords are constructed, and is there a common name for it?

I've provided examples below, but in case a link goes dead, the progression seems to be some sort of 7th progression with the bass and top note stepping down in half steps.

*Examples:*

- Learn to Fly - FKJ
- Porter Robinson - Sad Machine

  at 1:16

There are more examples, but these are what I can remember!

Comment: In the FJK track, you mean at about 1:28?

Comment: Yep! @topo morto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We call this technique **planing**.

Typically in tonal music, chords move fourths, fifths, and other skips. Only in a few instances do chords move by step, and *very rarely* do chords move by minor second. Furthermore, these chords are often different qualities.

But around the turn of the twentieth century, composers starting moving a single chord quality up and down by step, and we call this technique *planing*.

As far as I can hear, in the top example, the composer just planes minor seventh chords:

[image]

It begins with a Cm7, then progresses through a C♭m7 (=Bm7), B♭m7, and then a D♭/E♭ to briefly switch to the subdominant A♭.

The second example is similar.

We could also explain this in tonal ways: the C♭m7 is really similar to an augmented sixth chord that then proceeds to a dominant (the B♭m7), but typically a blatant move by semitone using the same quality chord is just understood as planing.